# how do i set Indeterminate state of a checkbox if i have a multiple files that have different attributes values?

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, checkbox

I'm trying to create a Properties form for selected items from my small file explorer[ListView] 
[like in Windows when you right click on some selected files/folders and choose Properties.]

the form shows Name,Location,Type,Size and **Attributes**

It's a [WCF service] server client application, so i get the attributes from the server from a method called **Multi** that starts in its own thread.

**The question is :** How do i set CheckState.Indeterminate if the multiple files that have different attributes values for [Hidden] and [Readonly].

[image]

```
WCF_Client.FM_ServiceReference.FileManagerClient client;

private void Form_MultiProp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread th = new Thread(Multi);
        th.Start();
    }

private void GetAttributes(FileAttributes fAttributes)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            if (fAttributes != 0)
            {
                if ((fAttributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden)
                    Hidden.Checked = true;
                if ((fAttributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly)
                    ReadOnly.Checked = true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void Multi()
    {
        foreach (Item item in itemCollection)
        {
            GetAttributes(client.GetAttributeOfPath(item.Path));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added all attributes in a list, then called Checking method that determines what CheckState should be in ReadonlyCheckBox and HiddenCheckBox, **Checking** method checks if `prev attribute == next attribute` to set the CheckState.

```
List<FileAttributes> listAttributes = new List<FileAttributes>();

private void HiddenInvoke(CheckState HiddenState)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            Hidden.CheckState = HiddenState;
        });
    }
    private void ReadOnlyInvoke(CheckState ReadOnlyState)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            ReadOnly.CheckState = ReadOnlyState;
        });
    }
    private void HiddenCheck(bool check)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            Hidden.Checked = check;
        });
    }
    private void ReadOnlyCheck(bool check)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            ReadOnly.Checked = check;
        });
    }

public void Multi()
    {
        try
        {
            long SizeAll = 0;
            int fileCount = 0, folderCount = 0;
            LocInvoke(Loc);
            foreach (ListViewItem item in SelectedItems)
            {
               // some other calculations..
                if (client.IsFile(item.ToolTipText))
                    TypeInvoke(++fileCount, folderCount);
                else if (client.IsFolder(item.ToolTipText))
                    TypeInvoke(fileCount, ++folderCount);
               // Adding Attributes to a list
                listAttributes.Add(client.GetAttributeOfPath(item.ToolTipText));
               //Size Calculation
                SizeInvoke(CnvrtUnit(SizeAll += client.GetSizeOfPath(item.ToolTipText)));
            }
            Checking();
            Finished("OK", true);
        }
        catch { } //in case user closes the form before it finishes
    }

private void Checking()
    {
        bool hiddenSet = false;
        bool readonlySet = false;
        for (int i = 1; i < listAttributes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (hiddenSet && readonlySet)   //checks if they already different then there's no need to check again
                return;
            if (!hiddenSet)
            {
                if ((listAttributes[i - 1] & FileAttributes.Hidden) == (listAttributes[i] & FileAttributes.Hidden))
                {
                    HiddenCheck((listAttributes[i] & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden);
                }
                else
                {
                    HiddenInvoke(CheckState.Indeterminate);
                    hiddenSet = true;
                }
            }
            if (!readonlySet)
            {
                if ((listAttributes[i - 1] & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == (listAttributes[i] & FileAttributes.ReadOnly))
                {
                    ReadOnlyCheck((listAttributes[i] & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly);
                }
                else
                {
                    ReadOnlyInvoke(CheckState.Indeterminate);
                    readonlySet = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I think this code does what you want it to do, but in a very convoluted way.

Comment: @david.s yea kinda, i've thought alot till someone answer my question so that what i got, it works fine for my application to calculate the other information too the same loop, but your way is a better answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the Hidden and ReadOnly checkboxes for the first file, then set them to Indeterminate if you find a file with a different attribute:

```
private void GetAttributes(FileAttributes fAttributes)
{
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        if (fAttributes != 0)
        {
            bool hidden = (fAttributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden;
            if (Hidden.Checked != hidden)
                Hidden.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate;
            bool readOnly = (fAttributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
            if (ReadOnly.Checked != readOnly)
                ReadOnly.CheckState = CheckState.Indeterminate;
        }
    });
}

public void Multi()
{
    FileAttributes fAttributes = client.GetAttributeOfPath(item[0].Path)
    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
        if (fAttributes != 0)
        {
            Hidden.Checked = (fAttributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) == FileAttributes.Hidden;
            ReadOnly.Checked = (fAttributes & FileAttributes.ReadOnly) == FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
        }
    });
    for (int i = 1; i < itemCollection.Count; i++)
    {
        Item item = itemCollection[i];
        GetAttributes(client.GetAttributeOfPath(item.Path));
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't try to use your code because i can't use `for` in `Multi()` because it also calculates some other stuff like `Size, Type`, I'm really sorry that i didn't mention that in my question its my fault but i think your code is correct, can you check for my answer if it correct 100% please?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use `for`. You can do this `Item item = itemCollection[i];` to use `item`.

Comment: sure i can, but the loop should be from index `0` to `Count-1` because there are some other information Im getting from `item.Path` and you takes the first index then loop from index `1` to `Count-1`.